# What Causes Toad's Slime to Harden so Quickly?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

While watching the first X-Men movie, I noticed that when Toad slimes Jean Grey, the slime has a very gooey, wet look to it. Yet, when the camera shows Jean moments later, the slime has already hardened to her face. Why is this? Are there any instances like this in the comics?

Comment: You seem to be somewhat obsessed with toad's spit. Perhaps you might want to become an expert in it and self-answer a few of these questions.

Comment: @Valorum - there's a year-old tag.  I don't pretend to understand why, but it's there.

Comment: Long story short, he is not the first person who was obsessed...

Comment: It's because of Spit Force.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of difference between comics and the movies: In the former, Toad's saliva is acidic, its his skin that produces adhesive resin that lets him cling to almost any surface:

> - Acidic Saliva: The Toad's saliva is highly acidic and can adheres to most surfaces and quickly dissolve most materials with ease.
> - Paralytic Resin: The Toad's pores secrete an **adhesive resin that allows him to stick to any surface** and paralyzes the nervous systems of any living organism that comes into contact with it. ([source](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mortimer_Toynbee_(Earth-616)))

In the movie it seems that both his saliva and skin produce the same stuff - sticky stuff that helps Toad to cling to walls like, well... toad.